# Which terminal emulators for Linux support VT320 / VT420 soft character sets?

Tags: terminal, terminal-emulator

It' s about the [Dynamically Redefined Character Set (DRCS)](https://vt100.net/dec/vt320/soft_characters) feature supported by the Digital VT320 terminal (and later models). Do any of the well-known terminal emulators like xterm, Konsole, or gnome-terminal allow to display such soft characters defined by the host software?

**NOTE:** The application must work both in an emulator, *and* on real VT hardware. This is why I can't simply resort on Unicode characters.

Comment: If they don't, then look at [SecureCRT](https://www.vandyke.com/products/securecrt/), a closed source VT320 emulator that has a Linux version.  I've used it (the Windows version) for 20+ years.

Answer (score 1):

The way to answer this is to check documentation, because `DRCS` is a large enough feature that a developer would mention it.

xterm (unlike the xterm-wannabe's) is documented, and the feature is mentioned in the FAQ, under [Ongoing/future work](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.faq.html#future_work):

> - soft (downloadable) fonts

Konsole and gnome-terminal have no useful documentation; you would have to determine this by examining the source-code.  It helps to know that `DRCS` is an example of `DCS` (device control string).

- Konsole's source code mentions DCS only in a summary of control sequences in ["old-documents"](https://invent.kde.org/utilities/konsole/-/blob/master/doc/developer/old-documents/More/ansix364.txt), which happens to be a copy of someone else's documentation. *"RSS"* is [*Richard S. Shuford*](https://vt100.net/shuford/terminal/).
- VTE (e.g., gnome-terminal), mentions soft fonts in its [source-code](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/vte/-/blob/master/src/vteseq.cc#L2359):

> `*    7: soft character set (DRCS)`
>         `*       TODO: ?`

There are (at least) two reasons why this feature might not be widely available:

- rarely used (the reason for the question)
- awkward to implement.  The soft fonts are basically low-resolution bitmaps, and using them in a nice way would require scaling them.

Double-size characters are a somewhat related feature, because of the scaling aspect.  xterm uses the X server-side scaling for *bitmap* fonts (which is readable but not **nice**), as well as TrueType fonts (by clipping, etc).  Not many terminal emulators provide double-size fonts (konsole does, vte does not).

Some closed-source programs provide the double-size feature (macOS Terminal for instance), but that does not imply the soft-font feature (here, macOS terminal does **not**).

Noting the comment about SecureCRT, I checked. It does not appear to do this, using [vttest](https://invisible-island.net/vttest/vttest.html) (I see it displaying characters from the alternate character set rather than the downloaded font, and it does not support double-size characters).  The test is kind of old ([1996](https://invisible-island.net/vttest/CHANGES.html#index-t960908)), but the feature has not changed.  Offhand, I would suppose it would be provided by some fairly old commercial program (and again, if the feature is not mentioned in the documentation, it likely does not exist).

Comment: The konsole doc seems to have been (at least partially) copied from the VT100 user manual & technical manual. But: It's good to see that the goold ol' xterm is still undergoing further development.

Comment: Actually it says it was inspired by a BYTE article, by "RSS" (using the manuals of course).